# I am fetching my Sanity data (hero) with useEffect but when I use the data in the return statement the website crashes

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch-api, sanity

When I console.log hero I get all the data. But when I use hero.tag or hero.heading anywhere in the return statement the site does not load.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'heading')

or

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tag')

```
const [hero, setHero] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
 client
  .fetch(
    `*[_type == "hero"]{
    background{
      asset->{
      _id,
      url
    }
  },  
  tag,
  heading,
  subheading 
  
}`
  )
  .then((data) => setHero(data)
)
  .catch(console.error);
}, []);
```

I can see its because the return statement runs before the data can be fetched from the API. I tried using async and await but I might be used it wrong.

Comment: Can you include a `console.log` of `hero` state once it's populated?

Comment: can you also post jsx?

Answer (score 0):

I got help from a friend and used axios to fetch the data (I don't think that was the main fix)

`useEffect(() => { axios .get('https://vve5jxlt.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/query/production?query=*%5B_type%20%3D%3D%20%22hero%22%5D') .then(response => setHero(response.data)); }, []);`

in the return jsx we added
`

```
    return (
        <>                                                       {hero.length == 0 ?
  <div></div> : <div>{hero.result[0].heading}</div>`
```

that wasn't my actual jsx but the point is that is the path to the result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).